# Problema com envio duplicado de formulario

Tags: javascript, html, formulário

Galera estou com um problema de envio duplicado de formulário.

Ele ocorre da seguinte maneira. Tenho um formulário html, quando o usuário da 2 cliques rápidos ou clica rápido no enter ele envia o formulário 2 vezes.

Eu tentei resolver o problema da seguinte forma.

Fiz o form assim:

```
<form name='form'  onsubmit='envia_tranca();'>
```

E coloquei esta javascript no começo da página:

```
<script>
        function envia_tranca() {
            document.forms['form'].submit();
            document.forms['form'].elements['envia'].disabled = true;
        }
</script>
```

Bom isso funciona no chrome e safari, porem no IE o bug continua, alguém pode me ajudar a resolver o problema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Método 1: "unobtrusive"

Use um código unobtrusive para desativar o envio do formulário após ele já ter sido enviado. Aqui está um exemplo usando *jQuery*.

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    $(this).submit(function() {
        return false;
    });
    return true;
});
```

### Método 2: validação `obsubmit()`

Também existem outras formas de realizar essa validação, por exemplo:

```
<form onsubmit="return validacao()">
  Input teste: <input type="text">
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var foiEnviado = false;    
    function validacao(){
      if(!foiEnviado) {
        foiEnviado = true;
        return ;
      }
      return false;
    }    
</script>
```

### Método 3: plugin jQuery

Usando um plugin chamado **Safeform**, o segredo é usar o método `data()` para validar caso o formulário fora enviado ou não. Assim, não é preciso ficar validando botões, no que o *Internet Explorer* manda muito mal.

```
jQuery.fn.preventDoubleSubmission = function() {
  $(this).on('submit',function(e){
    var $form = $(this);

    if ($form.data('submitted') === true) {
      e.preventDefault();
    } else {
      $form.data('submitted', true);
    }
  });
  return this;
};
```

Use mais ou menos assim:

```
$('form').preventDoubleSubmission();
```

Leia mais sobre o [jQuery Safeform](https://github.com/caxap/jquery-safeform)

Comment: bom consegui fazer o Método 2 funcionar, porém queria saber como chamar o Método 1 no form

Answer (score 0):

Já vi algo semelhante usando JQuery:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    $(this).submit(function() {
        return false;
    });
    return true;
});
```

Existe também um plugin chamado  [jquery-safeform](https://github.com/caxap/jquery-safeform) que resolve exatamente esse problema.

Comment: e como eu chamo ele em um form?